# Login on Instagram using python but it gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, authentication, instagram

I have made a code where I try to login to my instagram account but it gives me many errors. How can I fix them?

The code:

```
import pdb
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
dom = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*')

pdb.set_trace()
username = dom.find_element_by_name('username')
password = dom.find_element_by_name('password')
login_button = dom.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]')

username.clear()
password.clear()
username.send_keys('your username')
password.send_keys('your password')

login_button.click()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')

if 'logged-in' in driver.page_source:
    print 'Logged in'
```

The error:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 49
>       warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
>   UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
>       stdin=PIPE)
>     File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>     File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Programaciones Python\Pruebas.py", line 4, in 
>       driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>     File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 56, in **init**
>       self.service.start()
>     File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: The webdriver is not able to find the `PhantomJS` file. Make sure its in the same folder, and instead of using PhantomJS (since it is deprecated) use Chrome or Firefox webdriver.

Comment: Can you change the code to me as you say pls? : /

Comment: Just put your `phantomjs` file in the same folder in which your program (`.py`) file is or copy the path of your `phantomjs` file and put it while declaring the webdriver 
`webdriver.PhantomJS('<path_to_phantomjs>')`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong here: `Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.`

You can fix this by locating your `phantomjs.exe` file -- wherever you downloaded phantomjs driver -- and adding it to your `Path` environment variable. [This guide](https://testguild.com/how-to-install-phantomjs/) will help get you started in fixing this. The issue does not need to be fixed in your code, unless you want to manually pass the path to `phantomjs.exe` into your `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()` call.